# Every time I use the code " pip install pyttsx3" it gives an error I'm using visual studio code

Tags: python, windows

The error is:

> pip: the term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: You should be using `py -m pip install ...`

Answer (score 0):

you're getting this error because pip isn't installed on your machine, this should've to been done in the process of installing python.

- **first** make sure You have python installed in your machine:

```
C:>  py --version
```

you should get something like this:`Python 3.N.N'`.

- If you don't have python on your machine, go to the [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/). But If you do have it, then you only need to install pip by using the following command:

```
C:>  py -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

note: consider using virtual environment to isolate your project from the other project and from the system.